# Why google analytics dataset delete my old data in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have configured a GA4 bigquery linking, but the dataset only retains 60 days of data and I can't find a way to prevent it from deleting the old days.

In the configuration of the dataset I have the expiration in never as well as the partitions see screens below.

I would appreciate it if someone help me to solve the problem.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5FU7.png)

Comment: I presume you have set up a way to pay in BigQuery?

Comment: Hi Tony, many thanks for your answer. Yes we have also we have billing activated

Answer (score 0):

Once you set expiration date to never, only tables created after that will be affected.

You need to change the flag on older tables by yourself. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time)